# Socket.io авторизация с передачей данных через handshake

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express, auth

Я написал авторизацию для сокет-соединения:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
    handshake.cookies = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie || '');
    var sidCookie = handshake.cookies[cfg.session.key];
    var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(sidCookie, cfg.session.secret);
    if(!sid){
        log.error('Not session found');
    }
    redis.get('sess:'+sid, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            log.error('io.authorization -> ',err);
            return;
        }
        if(data){
            handshake.user = jsonParse(data);
            callback(null, true);
        }
    });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    var userLogin = socket.handshake.user.LOGIN;
    log.info("Socket is connect: "+userLogin);
    socket.on('msg', (data) => {
        log.info(data);
        socket.emit('msg',{text:'server say:' + new Date()});
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        log.info("Socket is disconnect");
    });
});
```

Все что происходит внутри `authorization` - проходит нормально, достается сессия с данными о юзере... Далее внутри `connection` я пытаюсь достать только что положенного юзера в `handshake`, но получаю ошибку с `undefined`. Почему его там нет? Что я делаю не так? Как правильно передать данные? Или ошибка где-то в другом месте может быть?

Comment: Можете добавить текст ошибки? Кое-что кажется подозрительным - то, как вешается обработчик - `io.sockets.on('connection', function () {})`. Не должно ли быть просто `io.on('connection', function () {})` ? Какую версию socket.io вы используете?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov нет, пробовал и просто `io.on('connection')` - результат тот же. Версия 1.3.7. Что вам даст текст ошибки `var userLogin = socket.handshake.user.LOGIN; TypeError: Cannot read property 'LOGIN' of undefined` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, правильный вариант авторизации для данной версии io и этого примера:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var handshakeData = socket.request;
    handshakeData.cookies = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie || '');
    var sidCookie = handshakeData.cookies[cfg.session.key];
    var sid = cookieParser.signedCookie(sidCookie, cfg.session.secret);
    if(!sid){
        log.error('Not session found');
    }
    redis.get('sess:'+sid, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            log.error('io.authorization -> ',err);
            next(new Error('not authorized'));
        }
        if(data){
            socket.handshake.user = jsonParse(data);
            next();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой
И так как новенький в этом деле, долго пережевывал ваш код
Позвольте вкратце!

Было:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
    /// ВАШ КОД
});
```

Надо:

```
io.use(function(socket, callback) {
    let handshake = socket.handshake;
    /// ВАШ КОД
});
```